# Is there a "magic" binary operation from which addition and multiplication can be derived?

Tags: abstract-algebra, diophantine-equations, quartics

I planned to make a one instruction set computer (abbr. OISC), and this question arose.

I wanted a "magic" binary operation $*: \mathbb{Z} × \mathbb{Z} → \mathbb{Z}$ so addition and multiplication would be equal to appropriate expressions involving only $*$s.

As I'd want $*$ be an algebraic operation, I presumed $x * y = axy + bx + cy + d$ for some $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then judging by the number of coefficients, I presumed the following identities should hold:

$$
((x * y) * k) * l = x + y
\\
(x * m) * (y * n) = xy
$$

for some $k, l, m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. The right-hand sides can switch themselves for an alternate solution.

Applying method of undetermined coefficients, the number of equations and the number of coefficients are both eight; they match. The system is quartic though; it would be very hard to find a solution.

Yet unfortunately, I have a strong intuition telling that there is no solution. The identity above for $x+y$ would force its left-hand side to eliminate its $xy$ term. I don't think it would be possible. How can I formalize this idea?

Comment: I see a vicious circle: you would define the * operation by $x * y = axy + bx + cy + d$  involving addition and multiplication for defining with it ... addition and multiplication ?

Comment: @JeanMarie The addition and the multiplication here are the usual operations on integers.

Comment: @Jean Marie No, not necessarily. In computer chips, addition is hardwired using bit operations, "xor" for the sum bits, "and" for carries. All binary logical operations can be expressed by just one ("nand", for instance). The whole process for addition is rather complex, naturally, and there are also shifts (for the carries), and multiplication is a still more complex operation, a combination of shifts and additions. So it wouldn't be entirely impossible, but unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

A solution close to what you proposed. With 3 registers $r, s, t$, the operation $r + st$ is sufficient for addition and multiplication.

$r = x, s = 1, t = y$ results in $x + y$.

$r = 0, s = x, t = y$ results in $xy$.

Obviously there needs to be some instructions to put $0, 1, x, y$ in the correct registers.

EDIT: actually this operation exists. It's called MAC or MAD.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation

Note that although we are talking here about a low-level CPU instruction, there is a high-level operation that does exactly the same thing: accessing an array element. To access tab[n], one computes $base\_address(tab) + n \times size\_of\_elem(tab)$

Comment: +1 , My answer has a binary operation using "a register & a Control Bit C" ; I did not include the "fused multiply & add" operation in my answer because OP is asking for a binary operation, while this becomes a ternary operation. Otherwise, good answer !!

Answer (score 0):

**OISC or "One Instruction Set Computer" is not Possible, because it means all Programs are just the single OPCODE repeated, which means all Programs are Exactly the Same !**

You must have Branching, Conditionals, Loads, Stores, Etc.

Now, if you want One Instruction to be given to the ALU or "Arithmetic & Logic Unit", even that is not Possible because the ALU does the Conditionals and Bit Operations necessary for Branching.

**In case you want to Divide the ALU into AU and LU and then claim that the AU has only 1 OPCODE, that might be Possible.**

The Single OPCODE is Increment, based on some Control Bit C, which means it increments the given register when the Control Bit is 1 ; toggle the Control Bit to get Decrement.

Use loops (Branching and Conditional Branching and Bit OPCODES) to calculate A+B via Increments only, by Incrementing A & Decrementing B, until B==0, then A will contain A+B.

Now toggle Control Bit C to get A-B.

Multiplication is repeated Addition, which requires More loops.

**In case you are OK with 2 OPCODES in the AU, then consider the 2 OPCODES Addition and Logarithm, with Control Bit C which you can be toggle to get Subtraction and Exponential.**

Comment: Don't you think that basing everything on increment operation will be very inefficient in the average ?

Comment: In older CPU Designs, MUL was very slow operation because it was based internally on additions ; This was very slow and thus the Time Complexity of Algorithms was based on Number of MUL operations involved. Using INC and DEC will make this OISC CPU Design even slower ! Not recommended, but that is what OP is asking about !